# What is a correct relational database design for storing client reviews for different vedors?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, relational-database

I am working on a database design where I have a table with Vendors and each vendor can have people reviewing them.

Here are my tables (I'm keeping it simple for the purpose of this question):

**vendor_table**

```
vendor_id | vendor_name | vendor_location | vendor_email       | vendor_phone
1         | User One    | LocationOne     | emailOne@test.com  | 000000001
2         | User Two    | LocationTwo     | emailTwo@test.com  | 000000002
```

**reviews_table**

```
review_id | customer_name | rating | review_text | vendor_id
1         | Customer One  | 5      | mediumtext  | 2
2         | Customer Two  | 2      | mediumtext  | 1
3         | Customer 3    | 5      | mediumtext  | 2
4         | Customer 4    | 5      | mediumtext  | 2
```

My question is: Does this make sense? Would it be better to create a link table called `vendor_reviews` with `review_id` and `vendor_id` as foreign keys? If so, why would it be better than the current design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it would make sense building a bridge table, to represent a n-to-m relationship, so that a reviewer can review the same vendor for every sale. but you need to restructure your tables a bit.

The review table

```
review_id | customer_id | rating | review_text | vendor_id
```

And a customer Table

```
customer_id | customer_name .....
```

On the other hand, if you have **no** customer table, you can't have a n:m relation ship.

Instead keep your design as it is only a 1-to-1 relationship between vendor and review

Comment: I'm having trouble wrapping my head around the the n-m relationship. In my situation,  the reviewers will be similar to a public comment section on a blog. So, anyone can submit a review. What I was thinking is that each reviewer (since they don't really have an account) will  just post the review and have the vendor_id in the same row. But I can't seem to figure out how the bridge table vendor_reviews would make sense (although I know one vendor can have multiple reviews). What are your thoughts?

Comment: if you have **no** customer table, you can't have a n:m relationship between review and vendor, because you have 1:1 between review and vendor

Comment: That makes perfect sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Not 1:1 -- There are "many" reviews for each "1" vendor.  So it is 2 tables like @nTuply started with.

If you don't identify "customers" there is no need for a table for them.  That is, anyone can write a review, make up a name, etc.  This makes it not many:many.

If it were 1:1, you may as well combine the tables.

1:many (or many:1) -- Notice how there is a link from each row in the "many" (`reviews.vendor_id`) to the "1" (table `vendors`).  You have an index on `vendor_id` in `vendors` -- namely the `PRIMARY KEY`.  You need an `INDEX` in `reviews` if you want to list all the reviews for a vendor.  A `FOREIGN KEY` is optional.

1:1 would share a primary key.

Many:many requires an extra table that is usually no more than two columns -- ids linking to the two tables.  Two `FOREIGN KEYs` is optional.  More on many:many -- http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table